# Buffer for async Udp Messages

Tags: c#, udp

I am using the following code to receive a message ( i am using this way because i am doing something while waiting for the messages) But, I was testing this connection and I am sending messages very close to each other but it seems like one of them get's lost. I have no clue how to fix this. how can I enable the 'read buffer' option or something similar?

thanks.. here's the code:

//function to receive UDP message

```
 public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;

        //IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

        Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref IpEndPoint_groupEP);
        received_data_from_client = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
        messageReceived = true;
        Logger("Received a message from : " + IpEndPoint_groupEP.ToString());
        u.Close();
    }

    public static void ReceiveMessages()
    {

        IpEndPoint_groupEP.Address = (IPAddress.Any);
        IpEndPoint_groupEP.Port = listenPort;

        //IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);

        UdpClient u = new UdpClient(IpEndPoint_groupEP);

        UdpState s = new UdpState();

        s.e = IpEndPoint_groupEP;
        s.u = u;

        u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);

  while (!messageReceived)
            {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
Console.writeLine("Hello")


}
```

I have the u.close because this function gets called more then one. I have a while loop, so the program reads the messages and does something with the message then when it's done it loops back and calls the ReceiveMessages function to start to read another message. And basically when the program did not receive a message it's shouting out 'Hello'

It's working like a charm. However i realized when two or more message arrive at the same time, it is only reading one of them and I am loosing the other ones

Comment: You do `u.Close()` in `ReceiveCallback`, why do you expect it to work more than once?

Comment: Sorry I just updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are closing the port between messages. Instead of doing that move the creation of the port outside of `ReceiveMessages()`

```
public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{

    UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;

    //IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

    Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref IpEndPoint_groupEP);
    received_data_from_client = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
    messageReceived = true;
    Logger("Received a message from : " + IpEndPoint_groupEP.ToString());
}

public static UdpClient CreateClient()
{
    IpEndPoint_groupEP.Address = (IPAddress.Any);
    IpEndPoint_groupEP.Port = listenPort;

    UdpClient u = new UdpClient(IpEndPoint_groupEP);
    return u;
}

public static void ReceiveMessages(UdpClient u)
{

    UdpState s = new UdpState();

    s.e = IpEndPoint_groupEP;
    s.u = u;

    u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);

    while (!messageReceived)
    {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            Console.writeLine("Hello")
    }
}
```

However because the only thing you do after you do `BeginReceive` is start waiting in a loop doing nothing, you might want to consider getting rid of the async callback and just call `Receive` directly and block on that.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I actualy am doing something during the while loop but it's doing a bunch of stuff and for sake of simplicity for the code I didn't want to include it in the question. I will be trying your methode and will let you know if it works or not!

Comment: Hello, When I tried the solution I got the folowing error : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(IPEndPoint localEP)

Comment: You only should to call `CreateClient` once, you call `ReceiveMessages` multiple times but pass the same `UdpClient` in as a parameter.

Comment: okay so i can call it at the begining of my main and that's it?

Comment: Yes, or wherever is appropriate. just keep the returned `UdpClient` and use it over and over again for the rest of the program.

Comment: Okay let me try this out